# Custom Checkbox is not rendered

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I am trying to allow my user to create a group and invite his friends.
I have already tried several ways, but its not really working out. My current approach looks something like this in the main template:

```
{{#each session.user.friends}}
    <li>{{view App.FriendSelectCheckbox userBinding='this' groupBinding='controller.content'}} {{nickName}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

And the custom view is defined like this:
(the whole thing is basically from this JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/durinthomas/cB3De/)

```
App.FriendSelectCheckbox = Ember.Checkbox.extend({
    checkedObserver: function(){
        if(this.get('checked'))
            this.get('group.users').addObject(this.get('user'));
        else
            this.get('group.users').removeObject(this.get('user'));
    }.observes('checked')
});
```

The problem is that the checkbox is not rendered. I know that there is usually a handlebars helper to render checkboxes or other built in views. But I thought this would be the approach to render just a view. And just for playing around I also tried to do
{{view Ember.Checkbox}} which is not rendering a checkbox either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox is successfully rendering for me: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qazuj/1/edit?html,js,output
The JSFiddle you linked uses an pre 1.0 version of Ember. Are you using latest?

Comment: Thanks in your example everything is working. I found the issue, it was somethong totally else (and also slightly emberassing)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my css, (I am still searching where it is coming from, but the reason why my checkboxes (doesn't matter which kind) are not rendered:

`@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/\/Users\/marc\/Sites\/ember\/app\/styles\/style\.scss}line{font-family:\00003607}}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}`

I know it hints where it is coming from, but its hidden in scss imports, It might be foundation or font-awesome or somethign like that.